# How to delete and merge old version of Ubuntu with latest 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on window boot of already dual booted system, but it still boot in start from old Ubuntu.

full explanation.

> 1. I had dual boot of window 7 and Ubuntu 13.10.
> 2. after rigorous effort I couldn't upgrade ubunut13.10 to 14.04.
> 3. So I planned to install Ubuntu 14.04 in place of window 7.
> 4. But My PC by default gets boot from 14.04. while I can boot 14.04 as well.

I want to completely delete 13.10 and wish to merge that space in 14.10.

Please help me step by step. I am new user at Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a full system backup!  Read [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) for more information: you're user type 4.
2. Make a full data backup as well.
3. Follow the [official Ubuntu Installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) until you're at step 4.
4. Choose something else
5. Delete the 13.10 partition
6. Create a new partition
7. Continue the [official Ubuntu Installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) at step 5

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)